# Run an ant script located on a URL

Tags: ant

Would it be possible to run an ant script hosted on a URL (without downloading/caching the file locally)? Something like: ant -f http://localhost/build.xml (which doesn't work)? I'd be happy to run ant embedded should this help. Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Why? Just download it and run it, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I have lots of machines (e.g cloud) and lots of things to run on them. This becomes messy if the script fails and I'm left with lots of files. I could workaround that using a work directory, but still not nice. Why not having -f taking a URL though?

Comment: It is not possible, as discussed on the dev list http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/201111.mbox/%3cCAOC9no1njcDW84vHjYPHrEae8TBn7h8QZ0gyy3mNCsf+efjy7g@mail.gmail.com%3e - however there is a patch for that here: https://github.com/cederberg/ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [Ant Server task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/server_tasks.html) from [Ant Addon AntContrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) or use it's sources as base for your own task. Seems as the antcontrib project ain't active anymore. Their latest release [antcontrib 1.0b3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/) is from 2006.

Comment: I looked at that, but unfortunately in this scenario the commands are ran in the ant server space which is not good for me. Will probably patch the ant with the patch from github I found from the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, as discussed on the dev list mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/201111.mbox/… - however there is a patch for that here: github.com/cederberg/ant